# PHP Sum function with callback function

Tags: php, callback, sum

I get some data structure from database:

```
object {
  currency,
  rate,
  amount
}
```

I want find some function like: $data.sum($a => $a.amount) for return sum of amount. But I can't find it. So a have write this:

```
array_sum(array_map(function($obj) {
  return $obj->amount;
}, $transferList));
```

Is any easiest way?

Comment: there's [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array_reduce), but I don't think it gets any easier (though less memory intensive)

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid a function call using [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) as in

```
array_reduce($transferList, function($v, $w) {
    return $v + $w->amount;
}, 0);
```

Or just do it in plain SQL with `SELECT SUM()`

Comment: What about simply `return $v + $w->amount`?

Comment: @deceze yes, it's better. I just pasted the example from the man page. I'm going to update.